# Ganymed wont connect to windows in JAVA

Tags: java, ssh

I'm using [Ganymed](https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/) to run OS commands from JAVA. In Linux everything works like a charm. The problem is with Windows. I get the error: `There was a problem while connecting to [IP]:[port]`. I've tried to connect through localhost/router ip/internet ip and port 22/1023 and I've opened the ports on windows firewall and on the router as well.

I'm guessing the problem is that there isnt anything that listen the port like ssh in Linux. Am I right?

what do I need to do to fix that?

BTW I've looked on `JSCH` lib but `Ganymed` is much more simpler

Here's my sample code:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostname = "192.168.xxx.xxx", username = "xxx", password = "xxx";
        int port = 1023;

        try {
            Connection conn = new Connection(hostname,port);
            conn.connect();
            boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);

            if (isAuthenticated == false) {
                throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
            }

            Session sess = conn.openSession();
            sess.execCommand("ver");
            System.out.println("Here is some information about the remote host:");

            InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

            while (true) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println("ExitCode: " + sess.getExitStatus());
            sess.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarification: "Ganymed" in this case is something like a java SSH library and not the Eclipse Version "Ganymede"?

Comment: Yes is Java based SSH-2 Protocol Implementation. I edited the Question to contain a link to the project to the ones who dont know it.

Answer (score 0):

You should install open ssh on windows to keep the ssh server running, which would act as a listener interface for inbound connections